# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_User_Table_UserTypeTable"

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc, web

please help me with error.
I'm doing a project at school

I'm building a web but when I nbut when I do login and use stored sql I get this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2UxI.png).
Can you help me solve this error. I really need to resolve this error.

Answer (score 3):

As `insert` caused error (i.e. foreign key constraint was violated), it means that you tried to insert row into a *detail* table, used value for the foreign key constraint column that does not exist in *master* table's primary/unique key constraint column.

This is Oracle-based example, but the principle is just the same in any other database.

```
SQL> create table master (id number primary key);

Table created.

SQL> create table detail (id_det number primary key,
  2                       id_mas number references master);

Table created.

SQL> insert into master (id) values (1);

1 row created.
```

So far so good. But, if I try to insert row whose `id_mas` value (`5`) doesn't exist in master table (it has only one row whose primary key column value = `1`), insert will fail:

```
SQL> insert into detail (id_det, id_mas) values (100, 5);
insert into detail (id_det, id_mas) values (100, 5)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C0010223) violated - parent key not found


SQL>
```

What to do? Insert values that *match*.